# Mandrill's attachment without extension on Hotmail/Outlook.com

Tags: php, mandrill, hotmail, outlook.com, transactional-email

I guess there is a issue with Mandrill attachments x Hotmail/Outlook.com.

I can send e-mail attachments with Mandrill using base64_encode(). I am using the PHP library.

If I send an e-mail to Gmail or any other provider, the attachment looks fine. Downloading it and opening normally.

But sending to a Hotmail/Outlook.com, the attachments came with no extension/file format. By downloading, it can only be opened by adding the extension manually (for example, .pdf).

The code:

```
$file_data = file_get_contents($_FILES["test_file"]["tmp_name"])
$file_type = $_FILES["test_file"]["type"]

$mandrill = new Mandrill('MANDRILL_API_KEY_HERE');
$message = array(
  'html' => $html,
  'subject' => 'Testing',
  'from_email' => 'sender@test.com',
  'from_name' => 'Sender',
  'attachments' => array(
    array(
      'name' => 'Test PDF document',
      'type' => $file_type,
      'content' => base64_encode($file_data)
    )
  ),
  'to' => array(
    array(
      'email' => 'to@test.com',
      'name' => 'John Doe',
      'type' => 'to'
    )
  ),
  'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'sender@test.com')
);
$result = $mandrill->messages->send($message);
```

Any ideas? Is it a Mandrill or Hotmail issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Gmail and other email services recognizes the `type` attribute as above, but Hotmail only recognizes the file type by adding the extension to the attachment name (`name` attribute).

For example:

```
'name' => 'Test PDF document.pdf',
```

It look obvious, but Hotmail requires it. Sharing my simple knowledge, since I received no answers.